# Methods params are undefined on Next js Routes handlers

Tags: typescript, next.js, axios

## Can´t identify why my params are undefined

I'm currently learning how to use the new Nextjs api routes, but every time I try to use a param in the HTTP method I'm getting an error saying that's undefined.

I'm using prisma as my ORM and PlanetScale as my database.

Here is an example of the api route that I'm defining:

```js
import { NextRequest, NextResponse } from "next/server";
import prisma from "@/lib/prisma";

type params = {
  req: NextRequest;
  res: NextResponse;
};

export const POST = async ({ req }: params) => {
  console.log(req);
  const result = await prisma.meetUp.create({
    data: {
      title: "some title here because I can't get the request body",
      description: "pls help me",
    },
  });

  return NextResponse.json(result);
};
```

Every **req** log is saying **Undefined**

Here is the front-end component that is using this post method:

```js
"use client";

import axios from "axios";
import { ChangeEvent, useState } from "react";

const MeetUpForm = () => {
  const [meetUp, setMeetUp] = useState({ title: "", description: "" });

  const submitData = async (e: React.SyntheticEvent) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    try {
      await axios.post("api/meet", meetUp);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
  };

  const changeValue = (e: ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    setMeetUp({
      ...meetUp,
      [e.target.name]: e.target.value,
    });
  };

  return (
    <form className="border-solid border-black" onSubmit={submitData}>
      <h1>Create new meet up</h1>
      <input
        type="text"
        name="title"
        placeholder="title"
        onChange={changeValue}
        value={meetUp.title}
      />
      <input
        name="description"
        type="text"
        placeholder="description"
        onChange={changeValue}
        value={meetUp.description}
      />
      <input type="submit" onChange={changeValue} value="Create" />
    </form>
  );
};

export default MeetUpForm;
```

I'm trying to get this params to post that request body in the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are using `app` router and the code shared in your answer is from a `route.ts` file,

Change your `POST` handler from:

```
export const POST = async ({ req }: params) => {
```

to:

```
export const POST = async (req: Request) => {
```

---

Notice that `req` is the first argument now. If you need to get the query params from it, you can do:

```
export const POST = async (req: Request) => {
  const { searchParams } = new URL(req.url)
  const id = searchParams.get('id')
}
```